# Gap under horizontal menu

Tags: html, css

I am making a web application for my university work and I am beginner in HTML

I have made a list and when I hover over it a horizontal drop down menu with some buttons is shown.
[This is the image of main list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlEQs.png)

But there is some unnecessary gap that occur under the list when I hover it. This shown in Pic below.
[Pic of gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgaT7.png)

This is code of my index.html

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title> IWB Product Management</title>
      <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css\css.css">
      </link>
      <style> </style>
      <script src = "js\javascript.js"></script>
      <script src = "js\canvasjs.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body id = "body">
      <header>
         <img src="images\webhead.jpg" /> <br/>
      </header>
      <nav>
      </nav>
      <section>
         <div id="na">
            <ul>
               <li>
                  <img src="images\productlifecycle.jpg"/>
                  <ul>
                     <li><input type = "button" id = "plc" value = "Introduction" onclick = "valueintroduction()"></input></li>
                     <li><input type = "button" id = "plc" value = "Growth" onclick = "valuegrowth()"></input></li>
                     <li><input type = "button" id = "plc" value = "Maturity" onclick = "valuematurity()"></input></li>
                     <li><input type = "button" id = "plc" value = "Decline" onclick = "valuedecline()"></input></li>
                     <li><label id = "labelplc"></label></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="images\companystrategy.jpg"/>
                  <ul>
                     <li><input type = "button" id = "cs" value = "Cost Leader" onclick = "valuecostleader()"></input></li>
                     <li><input type = "button" id = "cs" value = "Differentiation" onclick = "valuedifferentiation()"></input></li>
                     <li><input type = "button" id = "cs" value = "Focus" onclick = "valuefocus()"></input></li>
                     <li><label id = "labelcs"></label></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="images\economicphase.jpg"/>
                  <ul>
                     <li><input type = "button" id = "ep" value = "Expansion" onclick = "valueexpansion()"></input></li>
                     <li><input type = "button" id = "ep" value = "Boom" onclick = "valueboom()"></input></li>
                     <li><input type = "button" id = "ep" value = "Recession" onclick = "valuerecession()"></input></li>
                     <li><input type = "button" id = "ep" value = "Depression" onclick = "valuedepression()"></input></li>
                     <li><label id = "labelep"></label></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="images\futuresituation.jpg"/>
                  <ul>
                     <li><input type = "button" id = "fs" value = "Prospering World" onclick = "valueprosperingworld()"></input></li>
                     <li><input type = "button" id = "fs" value = "Crisis" onclick = "valuecrisis()"></input></li>
                     <li><input type = "button" id = "fs" value = "Business" onclick = "valuebusiness()"></input></li>
                     <li><label id = "labelfs"></label></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <img src="images\manufacturingtechnique.jpg"/>
                  <ul>
                     <li><input type = "button" id = "techchains" value = "Technology Chain 1" onclick = "CalculateChain1()"></input></li>
                     <li><input type = "button" id = "techchains" value = "Technology Chain 2" onclick = "CalculateChain2()"></input></li>
                     <li><input type = "button" id = "techchains" value = "Technology Chain 3" onclick = "CalculateChain3()"></input></li>
                     <li><input type = "button" id = "techchains" value = "Technology Chain 4" onclick = "CalculateChain4()"></input></li>
                     <li><input type = "button" id = "techchains" value = "Technology Chain 5" onclick = "CalculateChain5()"></input></li>
                     <li><input type = "button" id = "techchains" value = "Technology Chain 6" onclick = "CalculateChain6()"></input></li>
                     <li><label id = "labelmt"></label></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <input type = "button" id = "button" value = "Compare Chains" onclick = "CalculateComparison()"></input>
      </section>
      <aside>
      </aside>
      <footer>
      </footer>
      <div id = "content">   
      </div>
      <div id="">
      </div>
      <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 350px; width: 100%;">
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

And my css code is as under

```
 {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
 }
 body {
     padding: 0px;
     font: 18px Arial;
     background-color: #203052;
     width: 1320px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     background-image: url('../images/factory.jpg');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: center top;
 }
 header {
     width: 1320px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     background-color: red;
 }
 section {
     width: 500px;
     overflow: auto;
     float: left;
     margin: 0 auto;
     text-align: center;
 }
 section ul {
     list-style-type: none;
     margin: 0px auto;
     padding: 0px;
     text-align: left;
 }
 section ul li {
     list-style-type: none;
     margin: 0px auto;
     padding: 0px;
 }
 section ul ul {
     display: none;
 }
 section ul ul li {
     display: inline-block;
 }
 section ul li:hover ul {
     display: inline-block
 }
 #plc {
     width: 60px;
     height: 125px;
 }
 #button {
     width: 150px;
     height: 50px;
 }
 aside {
     width: 952px;
     overflow: auto;
     color: blue;
     background-color: black;
     float: left;
 }
 #chartContainer {
     display: block;
     overflow: auto;
 }
```

The link for the whole page is available at learnhtmlkiani.base.pk Please have a look on it and help me out

Comment: link of this is problem is http://learnhtmlkiani.base.pk/

Comment: Put in a jsfiddle and I'll have a play with it

Comment: There are a couple of wrong things with your code. For instance, id proprerty should be unique.

Comment: #plc {
    width: 60px;
    /* height: 125px; */
}

your problem is here. Fix the height of your buttons and it will work fine.

Comment: Along with the errors in your markup, you are missing a required doctype which puts you into quirks mode and you  will continue to have problems with this until you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add in your CSS:

```
section #na > ul > li { position: relative; }
section #na > ul ul { position: absolute; }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of wrong things with your code. 
For instance, an id should be unique, but you're sistematically repeating them.
You're using ids where you should be using classes.

Also, the problem lies with your `#plc` buttons.

You should remove the line

```
#plc { width: 60px; /* height: 125px; */ }
```

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/40u2Lwow/) for an example.

Comment: In need large buttons with height of 125px, 

I have replaced id with classes.

Answer (score 0):

Answer above is correct; there a couple of things wrong with your code. To solve the gaps between your images though, you need to have them `display: block;`. I went to the link you provided, and added this property to your images with css—this solved your problem.

Comment: If I will change the code as in above comment then height of my button will be less.
I need to have height of 125 px.

Where exactly I have to write display: block can you go the link learnhtmlkiani.base.pk solve it for me. 

Thanks in advance.